# How to get data from columns without index

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am a beginner with Python and I am using Matplotlib and Pandas to create a stacked area plot (like this https://python-graph-gallery.com/251-stacked-area-chart-with-seaborn-style/). Unfortunately it does not work. I have the following file with data:
[image]

Now I need to store the values from each column and for that I use the following commands:

```
    ts_1 = wind_data.Building_1;
    ts_2 = wind_data.Building_2;
    ts_3 = wind_data.Building_3;
    ts_4 = wind_data.Building_4;
    ts_5 = wind_data.Building_5
y= [ts_1, ts_2, ts_3, ts_4, ts_5];
```

If I use this now in the command from the example link above:

```
# library
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Data
x=range(1,6)


# Plot
plt.stackplot(x,y, labels=['A','B','C'])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I get an error message. I think the problem is that when I read the single columns in the variables ts_1 I don't get the values alone, I also get the indexes as you can see in this picture:[image]

I hope that I can create the stackplot if I can only store the values in the variables of the columns without the indexes. What do I have to do for this?

EDIT: Screenshot of jupyter trying to incorporate the comments of YOLO:
[image]

Screenshot from Exel how the diagramm should look like:
[image]

Here is the sample data set:

```
Building_1  Building_2  Building_3  Building_4  Building_5
7.04    7.04    7.04    7.04    7.04
6.36    6.36    6.36    6.36    6.36
6.4     6.4     6.4     6.4     6.4
6.1     6.1     6.1     6.1     6.1
5.88    5.88    5.88    5.88    5.88
6.18    6.18    6.18    6.18    6.18
6.16    6.16    6.16    6.16    6.16
5.82    5.82    5.82    5.82    5.82
5.28    5.28    5.28    5.28    5.28
4.82    4.82    4.82    4.82    4.82
4.18    4.18    4.18    4.18    4.18
4.02    4.02    4.02    4.02    4.02
4.08    4.08    4.08    4.08    4.08
4.24    4.24    4.24    4.24    4.24
6.24    6.24    6.24    6.24    6.24
8.44    8.44    8.44    8.44    8.44
8.72    8.72    8.72    8.72    8.72
8.06    8.06    8.06    8.06    8.06
7.16    7.16    7.16    7.16    7.16
6.52    6.52    6.52    6.52    6.52
7.16    7.16    7.16    7.16    7.16
7.88    7.88    7.88    7.88    7.88
8.44    8.44    8.44    8.44    8.44
8.56    8.56    8.56    8.56    8.56
```

New Screenshot of the output taking into account YOLOS code:
[image]

Comment: firstly, it looks like `y` is a list of objects, not integers - secondly, I believe you'll need to edit your data to make an area chart - what are you using for your `x-axis` values?

Comment: Thanks for your ansewr Datanovice. How can I change y into a list of intergers? The data itself is suitable for an area plot. I can do this easily with Excel. I still think that the problem is, that the data variables ts_1, ts_2 ... additinally contain the indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

# sample data, in your case this is wind_data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B':[2,3,4], 'C': [5,6,7], 'D': [6,7,8]})

# from here, replace df with wind_data 
x = range(df.shape[1])
y = df.values.tolist()

plt.stackplot(x,y, labels=df.columns)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could also do:

```
wind_data.plot.area() # or you can also do df.plot.area()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer YOLO. Unfortunately, I do not know how to transfer this example to my data. I tried it but the plot looks really bad. I just copied your example and replaced the values in the brackets [] with my data variables ts_1, ts_2 ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ts_1, 'B':ts_2, 'C': ts_3, 'D': ts_4, 'E': ts_5})

x = range(df.shape[1])
y = df.values.tolist()

Comment: basically, just replace the df in the example with `wind_data` dataframe you have. It should work. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks YOLO for your comments again. I tried to incoorporate your advice. However it still does not look correct. I included a screenshot in the first post that shows the code in jupyter and the outputs. I tried in the upper picture to just replace df by wind_data as you suggested. And in the figure below I also changed the data variables A to E by assigning my time series variables ts_1 .. ts_5 to them. Unfortunately both ways lead to wrong outputs.

Comment: @PeterBe can you provide a sample dataset above? Just a few rows would suffice.

Comment: Hi YOLO, I have included the sample data set as you requested. I hope this helps. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks YOLO for your comment. Altough it looks better now, unfortunately it still does not look like it is supposed to because you can still the A, B, C data that should not be dispalyed as it has nothing to do with my example (I uploaded a new screenshot). To be totally honest, I do not understand your example code. You don't use wind_data at all in your example. How does Python know that it should use the wind data? Because somehow it displays it correctly altough I do not see any link to it.

Comment: Here an additional comment: What makes things really really strange is, that if I use Jupyter and rerun the cell with your code, the output looks quite different. Now, the wind data is not displayed at all, but just your example data. This is how it should normally work because, as said before, in your example I do not see any link to the wind data.

Comment: By the way: using the command: "wind_data.plot.area()" leads to the following error message: "<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc993e0b278>"

Comment: @PeterBe may be you are missing `%matplotlib inline`, check edit.

Comment: Thanks YOLO. Now it looks good. Thanks for your effort. Still my initially asked question is not answered yet. How can I get the data from the columns without any index?

Comment: you can do something like `ts_1.values.tolist()`